# How to improve spark rdd's readability?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

I'm new to spark, I found myself often was entangled with transform a tuple into another tuple, which could be very complex, like (r._1 -> (r._2._1, r._2._2), r._3), and got confused with it. Is there anyway to improve this?

Answer (score 4):

- Don't use tuples, define meaningful case classes. Instead of

  ```
  val rdd =  sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "foo", (2, 2.0)), (2, "bar", (-1, 1.0))))
  ```

  use

  ```
  case class Meta(someValue: Int, anotherValue: Double)
  case class Record(x: Int, y: String, meta: Meta)

  val records = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    Record(1, "foo", Meta(2, 2.0)), 
    Record(2, "bar", Meta(-1, 1.0))))

  records.map(record => (record.meta.anotherValue, record.x))
  ```
- If you use tuples prefer pattern matching with useful bindings over indexing.

  ```
  rdd.map {
     case (x, _, (_, anotherValue)) =>  (anotherValue, x)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `DataFrame`s where you can access the columns by name. This allows you to produce much better readable code. Also, you can store those frames as parquet files which not only are very storage efficient but also contain the schema information. The operations are implemented very efficiently and switching back to `RDD`s is often not neccessary.